# controller input stopped working in ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, steam, gamepad

This is exceptionally weird because it just happened as a result of updates (either to OS or Steam) but this pdp xbox one controller that I use just stopped taking inputs and an old fake xbox controller still works?

so something is affecting the driver?

I don't want to install xboxdrv because the precision and latency when using this software instead of native detection is worse.

also it requires more preparation whereas I use my computer for lan parties (of Towerfall and the like) and it's just better for everyone when I have plug-and-play functionality.

Anyone know why this might be occurring and how to fix it?

here's my sys info gathered by steam :

```
Computer Information:
    Manufacturer:  Unknown
    Model:  Unknown
    Form Factor: Desktop
    No Touch Input Detected

Processor Information:
    CPU Vendor:  GenuineIntel
    CPU Brand:         Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz
    CPU Family:  0x6
    CPU Model:  0x2d
    CPU Stepping:  0x7
    CPU Type:  0x0
    Speed:  3800 Mhz
    12 logical processors
    6 physical processors
    HyperThreading:  Supported
    FCMOV:  Supported
    SSE2:  Supported
    SSE3:  Supported
    SSSE3:  Supported
    SSE4a:  Unsupported
    SSE41:  Supported
    SSE42:  Supported
    AES:  Supported
    AVX:  Supported
    CMPXCHG16B:  Supported
    LAHF/SAHF:  Supported
    PrefetchW:  Unsupported

Operating System Version:
    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (64 bit)
    Kernel Name:  Linux
    Kernel Version:  4.15.0-36-generic
    X Server Vendor:  The X.Org Foundation
    X Server Release:  11906000
    X Window Manager:  GNOME Shell
    Steam Runtime Version:  steam-runtime-beta-release_2018-09-03

Video Card:
    Driver:  NVIDIA Corporation GeForce GTX 760/PCIe/SSE2
    Driver Version:  4.6.0 NVIDIA 396.54
    OpenGL Version: 4.6
    Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
    Monitor Refresh Rate: 60 Hz
    VendorID:  0x10de
    DeviceID:  0x1187
    Revision Not Detected
    Number of Monitors:  1
    Number of Logical Video Cards:  1
    Primary Display Resolution:  1920 x 1080
    Desktop Resolution: 1920 x 1080
    Primary Display Size: 18.78" x 10.55" (21.54" diag)
                                            47.7cm x 26.8cm (54.7cm diag)
    Primary Bus: PCI Express 16x
    Primary VRAM: 2048 MB
    Supported MSAA Modes:  2x 4x 8x 16x 

Sound card:
    Audio device: Realtek ALC898

Memory:
    RAM:  15988 Mb

Miscellaneous:
    UI Language:  English
    LANG:  en_US.UTF-8
    Total Hard Disk Space Available:  491396 Mb
    Largest Free Hard Disk Block:  224933 Mb
    VR Headset: None detected

Recent Failure Reports:
```

I went into steam big picture to try and solve this and enabled detection of all controllers. but while my pdp controller shows up, it shows up as "generic gamepad" and does not take any inputs, I tried configuring it but it still detected no movement of the joystick and didn't respond to any button, while the other controller navigated all the menus with ease.

[image: steam big picture controller config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Xbox Controller shows up in 
    $ sudo lsusb 
In the Steam App: Steam > Settings > Controllers, I select the button for "General Controller Settings"
[image: Controller Settings]
I leave the "Guide Button Focuses on Steam" checkbox selected.
I select "Xbox Configuration Support" checkbox.
I select the controller I want to configure... Then the buttons to configure which category of settings.
[image]
When I go back to "Big Picture", it then looks like this:
[image: Big Picture]
If for some reason, it handles erratically... (I haven't noticed this on mine)...

## Dump the modprobe config and look for the xpad module in the kernel... You should see some output.

```
$ modprobe --showconfig | grep -i xpad | more
```

## Remove the xpad module

```
$ sudo modprobe -r xpad
```

## Add the xpad module back in

```
$ sudo modprobe xpad
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem.  I tried installing the xboxdrv, but that just made Steam stop recognizing the joystick.

I've got a PDP xbox controller, it does show up in lsusb.
I checked the xpad driver, and it lists support for my particular controller.  Is yours in the list?

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.c#L127

Sorry this isn't an answer, I don't have sufficient reputation to add a comment to your question.

Comment: for me installing ubuntu 18.10 instead of 18.04.01 fixed the issue. I'm guessing a reinstall of 18.04.01 might have also worked.